# Add individual items to datagrid in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, datagrid

I have a database with Table name "Product_Master" with column headers "ProductID, ProductCode, ProductName, ProductDescription, LandingPrice, SellingPrice, Stock, ProductCategory".

I have a  datagrid in my wpf window.

I am able to fill datagrid will all the values from the database.

The code is below.

```
        SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT ProductCode FROM Products_Master WHERE ProductName =('" + txtAutoProductName.Text + "') OR ProductCode = ('" + txtProductCode.Text + "')", con);
        try
        {
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = com;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            bSource.DataSource = dt;
            dgrdBilling.ItemsSource = bSource;
            da.Update(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

I would like to customize my datagrid with colomn names "Number, ProductCode, ProductName, Quantity, Tax, Total", and would like to add individual values from different tables.

How to do the same.

Added below

```
    private void txtAutoProductName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Products_Master WHERE ProductName =('" + txtAutoProductName.Text + "') OR ProductCode = ('" + txtProductCode.Text + "')", con);
        try
        {
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
            da.SelectCommand = com;
            da.Fill(dt);
            bSource.DataSource = dt;
            //dgrdBilling.ItemsSource = bSource;
            dgrdBilling.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            //dgrdBilling.Items.Add(bSource);
            da.Update(dt);
            newRow["ProductName"] = txtAutoProductName.Text;
            newRow["ProductCode"] = bSource;
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for customization in your .xaml:

First set AutoGenerateColumns, then add columns you need with proper bindings.

```
DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Column_name_in_table}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

This for adding the rows in code-behind .xaml.cs :

```
DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();

newRow["ProductID"] = txtBox1.Text;
newRow["ProductCode"] = txtBox2.Text;
      .
      .
      .

dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

If you want to the **DataGrid** to be notified with the changes in **DataTable**, set the **grid** **ItemsSource** to the **DataView** or **dt.DefaultView()**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great tutorial of how to use DataGrid.

http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

Set AutoGenerateColumns="False" if you want to have your custom columns defined.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In this examle header name is Image.

Have fun.

Comment: I have read that b4, but is it showing hw to add individual values. Because i haven't coded much in xaml. sorry. i am not able to get what that binding means.

Comment: @KaMaLMoHaN what do you mean by saying individual values? Like just one new row? Or individual value in certain cell?

Comment: I mean when i type product name and quantity in two textbox, then its product code, product name , quantity , tax and total should be shown in datagrid's first row, then after that if i type another product, then the corresponding values of that product should be added to the next row. You know the billing software. I am developing the one.